# How can I create a histogram of averages by month in Grafana?

Tags: statistics, histogram, grafana, influxdb

I have many years of temperature data in InfluxDB and want to use Grafana to render this data in a histogram.

The buckets should be by month and each bucket should be the average of the data inside.
Ideally the X-axis legend would be Jan, Feb, Mar,...

I've read the Histogram section of the Grafana documentation and found it of little help.

Does anyone know what settings should be used and how I should construct the query?
Thanks